# FCM: Total size of the payload data (4096) - is this still the same in HTTP v1?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

On google I can see in the section https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref (**Legacy** HTTP Server Protocol) that the total size of the payload data included in a message can not exceed FCM limits: 4096 bytes for most messages. Is this still true for the new HTTP v1 ? I can not find any public information about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The max payload size is still 4MB.  It's a limitation of the service as a whole, not any particular API.  See the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages).:

> Maximum payload for both message types is 4KB

Comment: correction the limit is 4KB not 4MB